# C# import sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server

Write ASP.net C# program, use readexcel to read an EXCEL file import SQLSERVER, I use the exception processing, even if there is abnormal response, but the file import has been successful part of the data, at this time how to restore before import. In what way?

code:

```cs
protected void Upad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileFullname = this.FileUpload1.FileName;
            string dataName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            string fileName = fileFullname.Substring(fileFullname.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string type = fileFullname.Substring(fileFullname.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            if (type == "xlsx" || type == "xls")
            {
                this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("upfiles/") + "\\" + dataName + "." + type);
                string ProImg = Server.MapPath("./") + "upfiles\\" + dataName + "." + type;

                DataTable dt = ReadExcel(ProImg, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    model.orgid = dt.Rows[i]["X1"] + "00".ToString();
                    model.orgname = dt.Rows[i]["X2"].ToString();
                    model.Unumber = dt.Rows[i]["X3"].ToString();
                    model.percode = dt.Rows[i]["X4"].ToString();
                    model.pername = Convert.ToString(getleftid.catetype(dt.Rows[i]["X5"].ToString(), 1));
                    model.perdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["X6"].ToString());
                    model.pernum = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["X7"]);
                    model.addname = Request.Cookies["Admin"].Value.ToString();
                    model.addtime = DateTime.Now;
                    bll.Add(model);
                }
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('ok" + dt.Rows.Count + "rows！');</script>");
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('ok：|xlsx|xls|');</script>");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('HI，fail！SQLerror，请重新导入');</script>");

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand your question.  In particular this is only nonsense to me: "but the file import has been successful part of the data, at this time how to restore before import. In what way"

Comment: I suspect this is due to a language barrier, but I don't follow what you are asking here. The statements are in quite broken English. I *think* you're asking how to return a table to how it was previously? if you want to return the *whole database* to how it was before, use a backup of the database taken before the changes. If it's just the table, you can `DELETE` the rows that have `INSERTED` since, however, if you've `UPDATE`d them you won't have a copy of what they were before. This is when things like history tables and/or transactions that rollback on errors are important.

Comment: Note if you have no backup, and have no way of identify new rows you have no way to "restore" the table to how it was before. There is no "undo" button in SQL Server once you have committed the transaction.

Comment: Use a Transaction? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu thanks! Use the delete method to solve the problem